# Magento 1.9.3.2 returning black page after EAV and WSC refresh

Tags: magento

Earlier today I refreshed "EAV types and attributes" and "Web Services Configuration" and now my category and product pages return as blank.

I turned on error display and it's giving me this:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function addToChildGroup() on a non-object in /home/mywebsite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php on line 819
```

This is also appearing at the bottom of certain admin pages:

```
    Array
(
    [type] => 2
    [message] => vsprintf(): Too few arguments
    [file] => /home/screaman/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php
    [line] => 416
)
```

I don't know where to go from here, any suggestions?

Magento 1.9.3.2

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I solved it anyways. I copied catalog.xml from a different theme into my theme's folder and everything is back to normal. No idea what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Copied catalog.xml from a different theme into my theme's folder and everything is back to normal.